# How can I change the power of the numbers in axis of the plotted figure?

Tags: matlab

I want to plot `z=(x,y)` in which x and y are arrays with large numbers (for example, `6.3251e8`). Matlab just changes the power of the numbers in the figure(for example `0.63251e9`). I want the numbers of the axis to be crossed in `10e10` (for example `0.063251e10`). How can I change the numbers in the figure?

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158707-force-scientific-notation-in-axes

Comment: See if [this](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161853) helps.